# Adding a last row using KQL to show grand total based on column values

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have data in following format

```
let T = datatable(OperationName:string, Result:string)
[
   "Method1" , "success",
   "Method1" , "failure",
   "Method1" , "success",
   "Method1" , "success",
   "Method1" , "success",
   "Method1" , "failure",
   "Method2" , "success",
   "Method2" , "failure",
   "Method2" , "failure",
];
T 
| summarize success = countif(Result == "success")
           ,failure = countif(Result == "failure")
           ,total   = count()
            by OperationName
```

Which displays the number of successes and failures per method along with the total.

[image]

Is it possible to calculate a grand total value, which is the sum of the total column values, and display it at the end of the last row, as shown below?

[image]

Comment: I tried to get result as mentioned in question but it is displaying as a new column. Here is [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/lTV0cR6.png) of the result. Let me know if it works for you, I can share the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try `union`ing with a row that is an aggregation of the aggregated table.

for example:

```
let T = datatable(OperationName: string, Result: string)
[
    "Method1", "success",
    "Method1", "failure",
    "Method1", "success",
    "Method1", "success",
    "Method1", "success",
    "Method1", "failure",
    "Method2", "success",
    "Method2", "failure",
    "Method2", "failure",
];
T 
| summarize
    success = countif(Result == "success"),
    failure = countif(Result == "failure"),
    total   = count()
 by OperationName
| as hint.materialized=true T
| union (T | summarize success = sum(success), failure = sum(failure), total = sum(total) by OperationName = "Grand Total")
```

| OperationName | success | failure | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Method2 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Method1 | 4 | 2 | 6 |
| Grand Total | 5 | 4 | 9 |

or, if you're interested in a less-intuitive and less-structured output (for reasons of your own):

```
let T = datatable(OperationName: string, Result: string)
[
    "Method1", "success",
    "Method1", "failure",
    "Method1", "success",
    "Method1", "success",
    "Method1", "success",
    "Method1", "failure",
    "Method2", "success",
    "Method2", "failure",
    "Method2", "failure",
];
T 
| summarize
    success = countif(Result == "success"),
    failure = countif(Result == "failure"),
    total   = count()
 by OperationName
| as hint.materialized=true T
| union (T | summarize total = sum(total) by OperationName = "")
| extend total = case(isempty(OperationName), strcat("Grand Total = ", total), tostring(total))
```

| OperationName | success | failure | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Method2 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Method1 | 4 | 2 | 6 |
|  |  |  | Grand Total = 9 |

Comment: Thanks, Yoni. Is it possible  have  "Grand Total = 9"  displayed as last row under total column? The screen shot in the original post show the desired output.

Comment: `total` is a strongly-typed column with type "long". it makes little sense to me to convert it to a string-typed column, just to include the "Grand Total=" prefix. that said, since you asked to do so, i've included it in the answer now

Comment: Thanks! "Grandtotal" is not a valid operation name so it cannot show up in that column.